# .NET Core, binding string to collection with validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, mode

There's controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFoo([FromQuery] FooParams params)
{
    // ...
}
```

Endpoint is supposed to have parameter `x=1,2,3`. What I want to achieve:

1. convert string value `1,2,3` to `IReadOnlyCollection<string>` (~`new HashSet<string> { "1", "2", "3" }`)
2. validate value of property before converting (applying regular expression)

Here's model:

```
class FooParams
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^\\d+(,\\d+)*$")]
    [BindProperty(Name = "x")]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Params { get; set; }

    // ... more properties here
}
```

### Binding

[Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) states that:

> Custom model binders: ... Typically shouldn't be used to convert a string into a custom type, a TypeConverter is usually a better option.

So I was about to write my custom `TypeConverter` like this:

```
public class FooTypeConverter : CollectionConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) =>
        sourceType == typeof(string);

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) =>
        destinationType == typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<string>);

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var plainValue = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(plainValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var values = plainValue
            .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(v => v.Trim());

        return new HashSet<string>(values);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to apply `[TypeConverter(typeof(FooTypeConverter))]` to property itself. Only place where `TypeCovnerterAttribute` is not ignored is when I set it for whole model class, but doing so makes converter bit more complicated.

Another approach would be to set my type converter to `IReadOnlyCollection<string>` like this (in `Startup.cs`):

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<string>), new TypeConverterAttribute(FooTypeConverter));
```

... but this way I'm "configuring" behavior of model somewhere else, which may not be clear for me in couple of days (or anyone else).

Is there better way? Should I rather implement `IModelBinder`?

### Validation

My current attempt to use `RegularExpressionAttribute` failed - seems that I'm able to validate destination type only. But that could be already too late to figure out whether parameter was missing completely or it had invalid format (implementing `IModelBinder` I could add validation error to model state, combining binding and validation in single place).